# Java: Partial path exists with Partial name of the file

Tags: java, file

I would like to know if there is a way to know if the file exists if I only know the path of directory structure and partial name of the file.

For instance, I would like to check if the following tar.gz file exists on following path:

```
/home/rah/data/download/lib/test@4.3-00@20120731.0.tar.gz
```

I want just my program to go on when I know the

```
path = /home/rah/data/download/lib/
partial file name = test@4.3-00@20120731
```

**(notice I'm missing "0.tar.gz")**. Indeed I don't want to calculate 0 after date in the filename (it could be any value 0, 1, 2, 3...).

So I want this to work:

```
if( filename.canRead() ) {
//
}
```

if file name is something like:  "test@4.3-00@20120731.*.tar.gz" 
where STAR (*) could be any number

how can I do so? or is this possible to check that partial path exists e.g.

/home/rah/data/download/lib/test@4.3-00@20120731?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) and supply it to the [File.listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) method. Roughly, it would look like this:

```
File dir = new File("/home/rah/data/download/lib/");

// list the files using a anonymous FileFilter
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.getName().startsWith("test@4.3-00@20120731");
    }
});
```

Comment: Also check out Apache Commons IO for some useful re-usable filters. For this case, use PrefixFileFilter and SuffixFileFilter: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

well you have to do it manually, list down all files in folder and compare each file start with your matching criteria,

Fo commons io you can do following

```
FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/home/"), new PrefixFileFilter("data"), null)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java SE 7 you could use the new watch service: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will want to have a look [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html).

The basic idea would be to use the [File.listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) method, passing in you filter & check to see if the resulting array is 0 in length or not

**UPDATED with example @ OPs request**

It's relatively simple, as others have already pointed out.

```
File path = new File("/home/rah/data/download/lib");
File[] listFiles = path.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {

        String name = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        return name.startsWith("test@4.3-00@20120731");

    }

});

if (listFiles.length == 0) {

    // File does not exit

} else {

    // File exists

}
```

You should really construct your own `FileFilter` that you can pass in the `String` you need to match, but I'll leave that up to

As also pointed out, you could check out Apache's CommonIO API

Comment: thank you for your reply. I saw your answer after update of my question. Can you please give me example code? thanks.